# toggle button is not working fine on While loop

Tags: php, jquery, css

How can i make slideToggle work to all my queries because the slideToggle is working only on the first query. Can anyone help me for this?

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#SendCopy").click(function(){
    $("#users").slideToggle("slow");                              
});                        
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php
while($get = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input type="text" name="doc_no" value="<?=$get['doc_no']?>">
<div id="SendCopy"><input type="button" value="SendCopy" class="btn btn-default"></div>
<div id="users">
    <span><strong>Quality Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['quality_manager'];?></span></span><br>
    <span><strong>Technical Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['technical_manager'];?></span></span><br>
    <span><strong>Top Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['top_manager'];?></span></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS style

```
#status{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Where is `SendCopy` and `users` element?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense I'm afraid - I guess there is a language barrier? How does the javascript relate to the HTML or the PHP?

Comment: You need to use class, instead ID, ID's can't be duplicated. So, change your id's to classes, and change JQuery, accordingly (use class selector). If it doesn't work - send us your HTML output, css, and JS code...

Comment: Sorry I'm just a newbie on JS . I just read same problems with this and they recommend also classes.  Can you help me where to put that classes .. Thankyou

Comment: My code is POSTED already. HTML JS and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Class instead of ID , because while loop create ID duplication, try this..

```
<?php
while($get = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<input type="text" name="doc_no" value="<?=$get['doc_no']?>">
<div class="SendCopy"><input type="button" value="SendCopy" class="btn btn-default"></div>
<div class="users">
    <span><strong>Quality Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['quality_manager'];?></span></span><br>
    <span><strong>Technical Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['technical_manager'];?></span></span><br>
    <span><strong>Top Mngr: </strong><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?=$get['top_manager'];?></span></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and js code like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".SendCopy").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".users").slideToggle("slow");                              
});                        
});
```